# How to reformat an array of arrays (or tuples) into an array of higher dimension

Tags: arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, julia

Consider these two one-dimensional array of tuples and array

```
a = [ (x,x,x)  for x=1:5 ]
b = [ [x,x,x]  for x=1:5 ]
c = [ {x,x,x}  for x=1:5 ]
```

What is the easiest way to format these arrays `a` `b` or `c` into the array `d`?

```
d = reshape(repeat([x for x=1:5],outer=[3]),5,3)
5x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  1
 2  2  2
 3  3  3
 4  4  4
 5  5  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the auto-concatenation that happens with vectors, the best (shortest) way for `b` and `c` is

```
hcat(b...)'
```

For `a`, because they are tuples, I'd do something like

```
hcat(map(t->[t...],a)...)'
```

where I'm converting the tuples to arrays, then concatenating them.

Comment: Thanks a lot lainDunning!